# Detecting whether a BLE device is connectable on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a project for configuring beacons.  A certain amount of time after being powered on, a beacon becomes unconfigurable until it is power-cycled.  In order to show a list of the configurable beacons, I am looking at certain characteristics (Bluetooth device name, certain manufacturer data in the advertising packet). I also need to know if it is "connectable", i. e. if the PDU Type in the BLE advertising packet for the device indicates that it is connectable. I've searched the Android Bluetooth classes high and low, both in Android 4.X and 5.X and haven't been able to find anything that will tell me this information.

I realize that one way to determine the beacon connectability is to connect up to it, e. g.: `device.connectGatt(...)`.  However, I've seen it take over two minutes sometimes before a callback to `onConnectionStateChange` comes back with `STATE_DISCONNECTED`.  Also, there may be many of these beacons in an environment, and connecting up to every single one that *might* be configurable would be inefficient.

The iOS equivalent of this attribute can be found in the `advertisementData` dictionary under the key `CBAdvertisementDataIsConnectable` in the `CBCentralManagerDelegate` callback method `centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI`.

So, the question is: is there a way on Android to determine whether or not a BLE device is "connectable" from advertising data or scan result or ... ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE:** AS of the finalized APIs in the Android O SDK, the `ScanResult` class (itself added as of Android 5.0) now has the `isConnectable()` method.  Detecting connectable advertisements is possible only on Android 8.0+.  See here for more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanResult.html#isConnectable()

Prior to Android 8.0, unfortunately it is not possible.

A connectable advertisement is determined by the PDU Header byte 0.  You can see this in the example structure below:

```
d6 be 89 8e # Access address for advertising data (this is always the same fixed value)
40 # Advertising Channel PDU Header byte 0.  Contains: (type = 0), (tx add = 1), (rx add = 0)
24 # Advertising Channel PDU Header byte 1.  Contains:  (length = total bytes of the advertising payload + 6 bytes for the BLE mac address.)
05 a2 17 6e 3d 71 # Bluetooth Mac
```

The problem is on devices prior to Anroid 8.0, the Android scanning APIs give you no access to these headers.  You get exactly three fields in the callback from Android 4.x:

```
onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, rssi, byte[] scan data)
```

The scan data byte array starts **after** the header bytes mentioned above.  And from what I can see of the `BluetoothDevice` definition, none of the fields or methods tell you if it is a connectable advertisement -- the class is just a container for the bluetooth mac address with methods to exercise functions on the bluetooth stack.  And there are no methods in `IBluetooth.aidl` which is the private interface to the bluetooth stack (and what `BluetoothDevice` calls to get its info) that can get this flag.

It appears that this information is not passed up to the Java layer from the BlueDroid stack prior to Android 8.0.

Comment: Given that your assertions align with my own findings, I think the answer here is that there is no answer. :-(

Comment: This is now possible as of Android O

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible since Nordic's nRF Master Control Panel does this.

After some digging I think I know how it does this. I'm not sure it's the right way to do it though.

I tried using the [LE Advertiser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.html) and setting the device as connectable. In the Nordic app, a device is set as connectable depending on the bytes found at scanResult.getFlags().

I found that this code works for my devices:

```
int flags = scanResult.getScanRecord().getAdvertiseFlags();
if ((flags & 2) == 2) {
  //connectable
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  The `ScanRecord` object was added in Android 5.0.  Do you know if the nRF Master Control Panel only does this on Android 5+ devices?  If it works on Android 4.x devices, it must have another way.

Comment: I can not reproduce these results.  I tested this on a Nexus 9 scanning for a RadBeacon USB using the Android 5 BLE APIs.  I put the RadBeacon into connectable mode (verifying this using a TI CC2540 scanner), and the Android `scanResult.getScanRecord().getAdvertiseFlags()` returned 6.  I then changed the RadBeacon USB to be in non-connectable mode (again verifying this with the scanner), and `scanResult.getScanRecord().getAdvertiseFlags()` still returned 6.  To be extra sure this was not just a caching issue, I turned bluetooth off/on, then plugged in the beacon.  It still returned 6.

Comment: In my experience there seems to be some sort of disagreement regarding the "connectable" flag and the spec isn't completely clear about it (or I just haven't been able to find a complete definition). I have worked with CSR beacons where if you set the LE discoverable mode flag to true it also shows up as connectable and with Bluegiga beacons where the discoverable mode flag has no effect on the connectable flag. If you try the Nordic app you will probably find that your RadBeacon shows up as connectable. And yes, I believe the Nordic app works on <5.0 so there must be another way

Comment: I did some more research on this and discovered what this flags value returns.  It is the byte value of the Flags AD block in the advertisement, which does not tell you whether a device is connectable.  It tells you if the device is discoverable, which is a very different thing.  The bit values are:   bit 0 LE Limited Discoverable Mode
   bit 1 LE General Discoverable Mode
   bit 2 BR/EDR Not Supported
   bit 3 Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable (controller)
   bit 4 Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable (Host)

Comment: I can confirm that the nRF app shows the Connect button even for devices that are known to advertise non-connectible. This is on Android 6.0.1, with nRF app version 4.0.1

Comment: @PVS 8 years later and NRF still misunderstands these connectability values