# Finding advertisement channel of iBeacon/UriBeacon on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon

How can I find out the channel on which a BLE beacon was received on Android? Is it included in ScanRecord byte array?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is one of several pieces of information not exposed by Android Bluetooth LE APIs.  The advertising PDU flags (which tell you if the advertisement is connectable or not) is also missing.

See here for more information on these fields that are not exposed:

[Detecting whether a BLE device is connectable on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467590/detecting-whether-a-ble-device-is-connectable-on-android)